# data points misaligned when using a third value with position jitterdodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Edited with sample data:

When I try to plot a grouped boxplot together with jittered points using `position=position_jitterdodge()`, and add an additional group indicated by e.g. `shape`, I end up with a graph where the jittered points are misaligned within the individual groups:

[image]

```
n <- 16
data <- data.frame(
 age = factor(rep(c('young', 'old'), each=8)),
 group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
 yval=rnorm(n)
 )

 ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=yval))+
   geom_boxplot(aes(color=group), outlier.shape = NA)+
   geom_point(aes(color=group, shape=age, fill=group),size = 1.5, position=position_jitterdodge())+
   scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,24))+
   scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "#015393"))+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "#015393"))+
   theme_classic()
```

Is there a way to suppress that additional separation?

Thank you!

Comment: How does this code make a graph? I don't see any data being supplied.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. I can't tell what you mean by them being in the wrong groups, and can't test the code without the data

Comment: Thank you camille for the instructions. I edited the code and provided data. Hope you see my point here. Thanks in advance for any constructive tips on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, I think I get what you are trying to explain.  It seems the points are grouped according to `age`, rather than treated as the same for each `group`.  The reason for this is that you have not specified what to group together.  In order to jitter the points, they are first grouped together according to some aesthetic, then the jitter is applied.  If you don't specify the grouping, then `ggplot2` gives it a guess as to how you want to group the points.

In this case, it is grouping according to `age` and `group`, since *both* are defined to be used in the aesthetics (`x=`, `fill=`, and `color=` are assigned to `group` and `shape=` is assigned to `age`).

To define that you *only want to group the points by the column `group`*, you can use the `group=` aesthetic modifier.  (reposting your data with a seed so you see the same thing)

```
set.seed(8675309)
n <- 16
data <- data.frame(
  age = factor(rep(c('young', 'old'), each=8)),
  group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
  yval=rnorm(n)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=yval))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=group), outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_point(aes(color=group, shape=age, fill=group, group=group),size = 1.5, position=position_jitterdodge())+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,24))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "#015393"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "#015393"))+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]